# How to Return custom HTTP status code in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to return a 401 http status-code if a given apikey is not correct:

```
class MessageRestfulController extends AbstractRestfulController {
    # ...
    public function get($id) {
        if (!$this->isApiKeyValid()) {
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_401);
            return $response;
        }
        # ...
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => array(...)
        ));
    }
}
```

For my controller i have added `'strategies' => array('ViewJsonStrategy)'` because it is a AbstractRestfulController and should return json if operation was successful.

I am really new to ZF2 and dont know what the correct way is to implement such an exception.

The way i am currently doing it, does not work.

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: This will be also useful for any future readers who want to send a non-standard status code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129344/custom-http-status-code-in-zend-framework-2/27129634

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your controller already has a Response object, set the status code on that and just return

```
    if (!$this->isApiKeyValid()) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(401);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Zend framework 1 : 
$this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(401);

Comment: How do you render a custom 404 page then?