# How to use custom (non-standard) HTTP status codes in ZF2

Tags: http, zend-framework2, httpresponse

I'm trying to send response with a custom http status code `498 - Token Invalid` in a Zend Framework 2 application. This is obviously not working as standard Zend Response class does not allow for custom http codes.

So I have created my own response class that handles this http code and return it in my action:

```
$response = new CustomResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(498); //basic zend response objects throws InvalidArgumentException

return $response;
```

Although no exception is thrown, the browser says it returned 500 error.

How to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [HTTP Response](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Response.php) class in ZF2 strictly follows the [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) for the status codes. This is a good practice and an exception will be thrown by `setStatusCode()` method when you pass an unknown status code.

Anyway, you don't need to create a custom response object to return a non-standard HTTP status code. There is a `setCustomStatusCode()` method exists for this requirement.

Try this in any controller action:

```
public function myAction()
{
   $response = $this->getResponse();
   $response->setCustomStatusCode(498);
   $response->setReasonPhrase('Invalid token!');
   return $response;
}
```

Comment: This is great stuff mate! I should have analysed response class more accurately...